# <projectname>.wpp.targets ignores Release build

Tags: publishing, visual-studio

We are facing an issue with `<projectname>.wpp.targets` file. Here is our `.wpp.target` file:

```xml
<Project>
 <!-- Exclude Sitecore assemblies -->
 <ItemGroup>
   <SitecoreAssemblyListsToExclude Include="Assembly Lists\Sitecore.Platform.Assemblies 9.1.0 rev. 001564.csv" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <AutoPublish Condition="'$(AutoPublish)' == '' and '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' and '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' and '$(PublishProfile)' != ''">true</AutoPublish>
   <AutoPublishDependsOn Condition="'$(AutoPublish)' == 'true'">
     $(AutoPublishDependsOn);
     WebPublish
   </AutoPublishDependsOn>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

When we build the project it creates the folder structure like `<project>/obj/Debug/Package/PackageTmp/` and adds the project files in that folder.

This works fine, but we want a similar folder for the same project for Release build as well. So when we build the same project under Release configuration it should generate a folder like `<project>/obj/Release/Package/PackageTmp/`

We tried to change the `$(Configuration)` to `Release` but it did not work. Please help us what am I missing here. Please excuse my little knowledge on MSBuild.

Comment: Looks like you're using Helix Publishing Pipeline https://github.com/richardszalay/helix-publishing-pipeline ?

Comment: How do you execute your build? If from command line please specify full command you use.

Comment: @BartłomiejMucha I am executing build from Visual Studio Build option only. I intend to use it for Azure DevOps CI in coming weeks.

Comment: Are you using Helix Publishing Pipeline?

Comment: @RichardSeal We are using Visual Studio Web Publish Pipeline, not helix publish pipeline.